# PowerBI DAX to find value of a column from another column in same table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to match the `rankorg` column with a calculated measure ceiling and pull out the corresponding blackout value  -

```
ValMaxSequence = 
CALCULATE (
    VALUES ( org[Blackout] ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( org[rankorg] ), org[rankorg] =  ( [ceiling] ) )
)
```

I also tried a lookup function, but it needs column value, but I have the result in a measure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ceiling` measure is being calculated within the context of the `FILTER` function.

Try pre-calculating it before you use it inside another function.

```
ValMaxSequence =
VAR Ceil = [ceiling]
RETURN
CALCULATE (
    VALUES ( org[Blackout] ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( org[rankorg] ), org[rankorg] =  Ceil )
)
```